# Postgresql: How to inline filter an array?

Tags: postgresql

How do I select different parts of an array by filtering a different component of them?

For example, given the following table:

| id | bar | foos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | {'A Young Foo', 'Lil Young', 'An Old Foo'} |
| 2 | 6 | {'Another Old Foo', 'A normal Foo'} |

I would like to obtain the following result:

| id | bar | young_foos | old_foos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | {'A Young Foo', 'Lil Young'} | {'An Old Foo'} |
| 2 | 6 | {} | {'Another Old Foo'} |

Using a query similar to this:

```sql
select
    table.id as id,
    table.bar as bar,
    (table.foos FILTER (WHERE _ LIKE '%Young%')) as young_foos
    (table.foos FILTER (WHERE _ LIKE '%Old%')) as old_foos
from table
```

This syntax does not work, but it is what I am looking for.

Is there a way to do inline filters on an array?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Not only does your query not do what you want, it also doesn't convey to us what you want.  Nor does your description.  It looks like you are writing SQL-like pseudo code inspired by features of some other language, but without knowing what the inspiring language is, how can we understand its intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You have to do an inline select using `unnest` and `array_agg`, for example:

```sql
(select array_agg(f) from unnest(table.foos) f where f like '%Young%') as young_foos
```